# There is a data blob of hdf5 [600000,1,7,256]. How to do mean subtraction using Caffe in matlab?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, caffe

There is a data blob of hdf5 `[600000,1,7,256]`.The function 'compute_image_mean.cpp' in Caffe is not fit for HDF5. So how to do mean subtraction using Caffe in matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a matrix in MATLAB of 60K vectors, how would you subtract the mean in MATLAB?

```
X=bsxfun(@minus, X, mean(X, 1));
```

Now that you subtracted the mean you can save X to hdf5 and feed it to caffe.

Comment: Can I do it as the following way:there is a 3-D matrix X 7*256*600000.The mean of X is 2-D matrix.The mean matrix is named as Mean.Then    Y(:,:,i)=X(:,:,i)-Mean                                                                                         where i=1:600000.

Comment: @ZhaoWulanaren yes, but I suppose bsxfun is better

Comment: @ Shai Hi,does mean subtraction equal to normalization?That is,if I do mean subtraction ,there is no need to normalize the data.

Comment: @ZhaoWulanaren there are all sorts of normalizations. some are done in the middle of the net and not only on the inputs

Comment: @ Shai Hello,I get some trouble.If I already have deploy.prototxt,solver.prototxt,train_val.prototxt.How can I code in matlab to call function of Caffe to train my data set.I know  caffe-master\matlab\demo there is a demo code but it just for classsification not train.Is there a complete code about how to train one's own data set?

Comment: @ZhaoWulanaren I am not familiar with the MATLAB interfave

Comment: @ Shai Hello,I did what you told me but I got another problem,do you know how to fix it?                                                                                                          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36601019/datatype-class-h5t-float-f0413-085440-661201-17769-hdf5-data-layer-cpp53-ch

Comment: @ Shai Hello,I have some trouble.Can you give me some advice?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557209/how-to-use-caffe-to-extract-feature-of-non-images-data