# Datatype class: H5T_FLOAT F0413 08:54:40.661201 17769 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:53] Check failed: hdf_blobs_[i] -&gt;shape(0) == num (1 vs. 1024)

Tags: neural-network, hdf5, deep-learning, caffe, matcaffe

My data set is a HDF5 file consists of `data` with shape `[129028,1,12,1024]` and `label` of shape `[129028,1,1,1]`.
But when I run solver.prototxt, I get the error message:

> ```
> I0413 08:54:34.689985 17769 hdf5.cpp:32] Datatype class: H5T_FLOAT
> F0413 08:54:40.661201 17769 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:53] Check failed:   
> hdf_blobs_[i] -&gt;shape(0) == num (1 vs. 1024) 
> *** Check failure stack trace: ***
> ```

Comment: please run in shell `h5ls` to see the actual shape of your stored arrays

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\[caffe\]: check fails: Check failed: hdf\_blobs\_\[i\]->shape(0) == num (200 vs. 6000)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418027/caffe-check-fails-check-failed-hdf-blobs-i-shape0-num-200-vs-6000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you saved your hdf5 from matlab, rather than python (judging by your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36384243/1714410)).
When saving data from Matlab one has to remember that Matlab stores multi-dimensions arrays in memory in colums-first fashion (fortran style), while python, caffe and many other applications expects multi-dimension arrays in row-first fashion (C style).
Thus, you need to `permute` the data in matlab before saving it to hdf5 for caffe. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34431532/1714410) for more details.

I suspect that if you run `h5ls` in shell on the hdf5 file you stored you'll notice that the shape of the stored arrays are actually

```
data   [1024, 12, 1, 129028]
label  [1, 1, 1, 129028]
```

Comment: You are right! I saved data set in matlab using permute.                                                             I think I misunderstood what you told me before so that I got the error.Thank you very much!

Comment: Now I can train my data without any error! Thanks again!

Comment: @ Shai Hello, can you  give me some advice about my new question?